# How to know the members of a extended class in typescript

Tags: typescript, reflection

The following code let to know the names and the properties of the members of a class in typescript language:

```
export class Teacher 
{
   Id: number;
   Name: string;
}

var teacher = new Teacher();

for(p in teacher) 

{

 var typeField = null;

 switch (typeof (teacher[p])) 
 {

       case 'string':

         typeField = "String";
         break;

       case 'number':

         typeField = "Number";
         break;

       case 'object':

         typeField = "Date";
         break;

       case 'boolean':

         typeField = "Boolean";
         break;
      }

 .....
 .....
}
```

But if I extend the class in this way:

```
export class Person
{
   Id: number;
   FirstName: string;
   LastName: string;
}

export class Teacher extends Person
{
   Id: number;
   IdPerson: number;
   School: string
}
```

The previous code does not work correctly because it lists only some members but not all. Can someone propose me the solution to have the complete list of the members ?
Thanks.
M.P.

Comment: Could you please specify which members are missing in your view?

Answer (score 0):

*Your first example does not work as well. Or you are initializing your properties somewhere that you have not shown here. The problem is not with inheritance. The problem is with uninitialized properties.*

If you don't initialize your properties (either in the constructor or assigning a default value as part of property declaration) the TypeScript compiler will not create any properties for the uninitialized properties.

So in your first example the generated JavaScript is:

```
class Teacher {
}
```

... which does not have any properties your defined. And when you use `for..in` over the instance `teacher` it has no properties to enumerate.

In order to add the properties to the class, you have to initialize them in the constructor or during property declaration:

```
export class Teacher 
{
   Id: number = 0;
   Name: string = "";
   // Or initialize in constructor
   constructor() {
       this.Id = 0;
       this.Name = ""
   } 
}
```

... which will add the properties to the generated JavaScript so they will be enumerated as part of `for..in`.